# Sed multiple search terms

Tags: bash, sed

I am not getting the behaviour I expected from sed.

From what I can see, I should be able to use:

```
sed -e 's/findfirsthing/replace/;s/findsecondthing/replace/'
```

However I was unsuccessful. As you can see from the output below. Although I wanted to remove "ca." and "ca-a." from the search, it only partially worked.

```
macbook:labs alex$ cat ca_vip.txt
ca.1
ca-a.2
3
4

macbook:labs alex$ cat vip.sh
#!/bin/bash
    for line in `cat ca_vip.txt`
      do
        if [[ $line =~ [ca.*] || [ca-a.*] ]]
         then
             echo $line | sed -e 's/ca.//;s/ca-a.//' >> temporary.txt
               elif [ $line != [ca.*] || [ca-a.*] ]
          then
            echo $line >> temporary.txt
        fi
    done

macbook:labs alex$ ./vip.sh

macbook:labs alex$ cat temporary.txt
1
a.2
3
4
```

The output I would expect is:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Why are you using a for loop to read the lines in bash and echo them to sed?  Your entire script is almost exactly equivalent to `sed -e 's/ca.//;s/ca-a.//' > temporary.txt`, the only difference being that 'echo' will modify whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

your patterns overlap, better to combine them, also you don't need the loops.

```
$ sed -r 's/ca(-a)?\.//' ca_vip.txt
1
2
3
4
```

note add g suffix if you want multiple replacements per line.

Comment: OP is not clear what he wants with `sed -r 's/ca(-a)?\.//' <<<  "ca.1 ca.2 ca.3"`.